# Can a mark be added next to the highest voted answer in the question?

Tags: feature-request, answers

I view my answers in time-ordering (oldest first) - I think it makes it easier to see when one answer builds upon another (as I've seen happen often). However, there's no visual indicator that says that a given answer is the highest ranked answer in the question (or, the "community chosen best answer"). So perhaps a light bulb, exclamation point, or something like that should appear next to the highest voted answer in a question if the highest voted answer is not the accepted answer. If the highest voted answer is accepted, then it would just have the check mark.

This idea is really only applicable to the oldest and newest views, so I guess it depends on how many people actually use those views, but it would make it easier to quickly identify the highest voted answer when viewing in either time ordering.

Comment: A thought occurred to me - what if multiple posts have the same number of votes and aren't accepted? I'm thinking that there would be no marking as there isn't one "community best answer" in that case. But I'm interested to hear from anyone else on this and any other edge cases.

Comment: Was the thought so good you named it twice?

Comment: What if multiple posts have the same number of votes and aren't accepted? Then there would be no marking as there isn't one "community best answer" in that case. Still, interested to hear from anyone else on this and any other edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine the number of people who use those views is pretty paltry in comparison to the Votes order.

I also think that if you are really that interested in what the highest voted answer was, you could just switch the order momentarily and go to the top of the page.

Comment: That's why I said it depends on the number of users who use the time-ordering views. I'm hoping that if Jeff declines this, he'll post the number of people who use each view. If this will only help a small number of users, there's no need to implement this and I'll just do what I have been - switching views. But if it will help enough people...